# Snowflake: Insert null value in a numeric type column

Tags: sql, azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a case statement to rectify one business logic in snowflake:

```
INSERT INTO DB.table_b 
    SELECT
        CASE 
            WHEN UPPER(emp) <> LOWER(emp) THEN NULL
            WHEN emp IS NULL THEN nullif(emp, 'NULL')
            ELSE emp  
        END AS emp_no 
    FROM
        DB.table_a;
```

The *'table_a'* content as below :

```
emp
-------
ABCD
NULL
''
23
```

It contains character string, null, empty and numbers. So, the requirement is to take only numbers and empty values from the case statement since the column *emp_no* in 'table_b' is numeric type. In source table if the column value is string then we have to insert **NULL** value. But as the 'table_b' column is of type 'numeric' the null value is not getting inserted and getting following error

> Numeric value '' is not recognized

Answer (score 2):

Using [TRY_TO_NUMBER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_decimal.html):

> A special version of TO_DECIMAL , TO_NUMBER , TO_NUMERIC that performs the same operation (i.e. converts an input expression to a fixed-point number), but with error-handling support **(i.e. if the conversion cannot be performed, it returns a NULL value instead of raising an error).**

```
INSERT INTO DB.table_b 
SELECT TRY_TO_NUMBER(emp) AS emp
FROM DB.table_a;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can not use `IS_INTEGER` but for VARCHAR(16777216) it isn't supported

So a regular expression would be better

```
INSERT INTO DB.table_b 
    SELECT
        CASE 
            WHEN regexp_like(emp,'^[0-9]+$') THEN emp
            ELSE NULL  
        END AS emp_no 
    FROM
        DB.table_a;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Getting following error: Invalid argument types for function 'IS_INTEGER': (VARCHAR(16777216))

Comment: that is a big varchar i will rewrite the query to regular expressions

Answer (score 1):

As Lukasz mentions you should use the `TRY_TO_x` functions ([TRY_TO_NUMERIC](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_decimal.html), [TRY_TO_DOUBLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_double.html)) as these safely handle parsing the types, and return NULL if the parse fails. The extra note I will add is that both NUMBER/NUMERICs and DOUBLEs will parse `0.1234` but get different results, which you didn't mention as caring about, but I think is worth noting, so I am adding an extra answer to point the difference out.

The CTE is just to get the values into the SQL:

```
WITH data(emp) as (
    select * from values
        ('ABCD'),
        (NULL),
        (''),
        ('0.123'),
        ('23')
)
SELECT emp
    ,try_to_numeric(emp) as emp_as_num
    ,try_to_double(emp) as emp_as_float
FROM data
```

| EMP | EMP_AS_NUM | EMP_AS_FLOAT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'ABCD' | null | null |
| null | null | null |
| '' | null | null |
| '0.123' | 0 | 0.123 |
| '23' | 23 | 23 |

Answer (score 1):

You can test for amp being string and set the string to NULL. Only numeric values will go into the second case statement.

```
SELECT
        CASE 
            WHEN IS_VARCHAR(emp) then NULL else
                case WHEN UPPER(emp) <> LOWER(emp) THEN NULL ELSE emp end
        end AS emp_no
```